# Exceptions and operator overloading

Tags: c++, exception, operator-overloading

I have a class which represents bounding rectangle with overloaded -= operator which gets intersection of both rectangles. When there's no intersection I throw an error:

```
if(/* no intersection */)
{
    throw std::runtime_error("No intersection between rectangles");
}
```

My question is: if I implement a `-` operator using `-=` should I use try/catch inside it?

Should I do this:

```
operator-(rect1, rect2) 
{
    try
    {
        rect1 -= rect2; 
    }
    catch( std::exception &e)
    {
        ...
    }
    return rect1;
}
```

Or this

```
operator-(rect1, rect2)
{
    rect1 -= rect2;
    return rect1;
}
```

Comment: Why would the empty intersection be an exception?

Comment: Beacuse I need to signal in some way that there's no intersection

Comment: Why would `-=` "get the intersection of a rectangle"? Be careful with your operator overloads. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Comment: Did you consider `bool rectangle::is_empty()`?

Comment: I understand this principle but it's a requirement of the project to implement -= this way

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to properly respond to your question without knowing, in detail, the requirements.

My 2 cents.

`operator-=` usually modify the (left) object; `operator-` usually doesn't it.

So I think it's better do something like this (assuming that `Rect` is the name of the class and that a copy constructor is present)

```
Rect operator- (Rect const & r1, Rect const & r2)
 { return  Rect(r1)-r2; }
```

I mean: i think you should throw from `operator-` but (in case of intersection) return a new object, not the left operand modified.

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

You are heading into the wrong direction here. Even if you're the only person maintaining the code, you should still follow some basic rules of operator overloading.

Especially, the left value should not be modified on `-`, only on `-=` as this would come completely unexpected to the user of the class.

You should rather supply a method that states if the rectangles intersect:

```
class Rectangle
{
    bool Intersects(Rectangle other)
    {
        /* ... */
    }
};
```

Comment: "One of them is that operators should work as expected. That is, no exception is thrown when a simple `-` is processed."

Could you give some additional, respectable source of this rule?

Comment: You're right, this is actually a very vague sentence in my answer. I will strike this one. However, modification of the left value inside a `-` operator is my main concern as it would be completely unexpected to the user of the class.

Comment: So, there's no rule about no throwing exceptions from operators?

Comment: I don't think so. And I think I've written this with thoughts about obscurity as the question shows a `-` operator that modifies the left value, which is very obscure behavior. One example is an exception that occurs when basically two integers are subtracted - completely unpredictable behavior. So is an exception wrong in any place? Don't think so. Using exceptions as a way to pass information along? Not a good idea either. If you want to discuss the necessity and use of exceptions, please provide an example.